# How to generate n random variables from x using sample() function when x has geometric distribution?

Tags: r, variables, distribution

I am trying to write a function in `R` to generate n random variables from `x` using `sample ()` function when `x~Ge(p)` (it means x has geometric distribution). In my function I would like to use a `while` loop.
I think my function needs two inputs as size and p. I need also a `for` loop in my function. What I think will work is something like a below framework for my function:

```
rGE <- function(size,p){
for
i<-1
while()
...
return(i)
}
```

I would like to develope my above function in order to generate n random variables from x (when x~Ge(p))

Comment: Could you explain why you want to use a `while()` loop and a `for()` loop in your function?  (Is this homework?  Homework is allowed on SE; you need to show us what you've tried so far, we won't just write the solution for you ...)

Comment: No, it is not homework. Actually I have a PhD in mathematics. I am new in learning R. I am trying to write functions for some distributions in R.

Comment: OK, then, it would be great to get a little more context. From what you've written it sounds like you want to draw `n` deviates from a geometric distribution with parameter `p`, in which case @Waldi's answer should work, and be very efficient.  Or are you using this as an exercise to learn R (i.e. not homework, but still a problem where you main goal is to learn programming, not to solve a specific technical problem)?

Comment: I am using this as a challenge to learn R. Actually I would like to make rgeom () function myself and I think using a for loop and a while loop I can do it (I mean make a function to works exactly like rgeom y). But because of my weakness in R (since I am beginning in R) hinders me to get my correct function.

Comment: OK, that comment (not needing to include the disclaimer/apology in the last sentence) would have been *extremely* useful to have stated up front ...

Answer (score 1):

For a home-grown, inefficient (but comprehensible) version of `rgeom`, something like this should work:

```
my_rgeom <- function(n, p) {
   x <- numeric(n)  ## allocate space for the results (all zeros)
   for (i in seq(n)) {
       done <- FALSE
       while (!done) {
          x[i] <- x[i] + 1
          done <- runif(1)<p
       }
   }
   return(x)
}
```

I'm sure you *could* use `sample()` instead of `runif()` for the innermost loop, but it's not obvious to me how.  One piece of advice: if you're unfamiliar with programming, try writing your proposed algorithm out as *pseudocode* rather than jumping in to R-bashing right away. It can be easier if you deal with the logic and the coding nuts-and-bolts separately ...

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker. I have changed my code to: rge=function(size,p){
  for (i in 1:size){
        while(sum(sample(0:1,replace=TRUE,prob=c(1-p,p)))==0){
      i=i+1
        }
    return(i)
  }
}

but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rgeom`:

```
set.seed(1)
rgeom(n = 10, p = .1)
#>  [1]  6  3 23  3 24 13 15  2 20  3
```

Comment: OP said they needed to use a `while()` loop (suggesting that `rgeom` won't be a suitable solution)

Comment: I have made a function as follow: rge=function (size,p){ for (i in 1:size){while(p){return(i)}}}.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally written the below function:

```
rge<- function(n, p) {
  x <- numeric(n)  
  for (i in seq(n)) {
    j <- 0
    while (j==0) {
      x[i] <- x[i] + 1
      j <- sum(sample(0:1,replace=TRUE,prob=c(1-p,p)))
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
rge(10,.2)
```

I hope it really generates n random variables number from geometric distribution.

Comment: it doesn't seem to: have you tested it? Try `j <- sample(0:1, size=1, prob=c(1-p, p))` ?